# What values can be used in the tags of the method [DJIRemoteController setCustomButtonTags:withCompletion] in objective-C?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I'm trying to configure the C1 and C2 buttons in a custom DJI app. I found that I can call the method setCustomButtonTags:withCompletion, which is part of the DJIRemoteController class.

I tried to fill the DJIRCCustomButtonTags object to provide it as a parameter of the method, but I don't know which values are valid for c1buttontag and c2buttontag. Does anyone knows something about using the setCustomButtonTags method?

Answer (score 0):

Valid values are in range [0, 255] ([documentation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/RemoteController/DJIRemoteController.html?search=setcustombuttonta&i=0&#djiremotecontroller_setrccustombuttontag_inline)).

You can set you own values, but it doesn't make the buttons do anything. Instead you could read the values after they are set by DJI's own application, add button listeners, and do some stuff when button state changes.

As far as I know, the values used by DJI's application are not documented anywhere. So you'd have to find out their meaning one by one. And then implement the functionality one by one...

Here is an example (for Android) for implementing button listeners: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/286